# R Stacked Bar Chart for Comparing Across Groups

Tags: r, ggplot2, bar-chart

I'm trying to make a stacked R bar chart for a Likert Scale survey that compares responses to a single quesitons across multiple demographic groups.

For example, I'd like one bar to be the whole survey, one bar to be how women answered the question, one to be how men, one to be how people who were "religious" answered it, etc.

I have code for a single stacked bar in ggplot, but cannot figure out how to combine these multiple demographic variables (since they aren't a single variable).

Here is a drawing of what I'd like the graph to look like.

[image]

Here is the code I have now:

```
survey %>%
    select(Q2) %>%
    mutate(Q2 = as.factor(Q2)) %>%
    mutate(Q2 = factor(Q20, levels = c("Always or almost always", "Generally", "Not generally", "Never or almost never", "NA"))) %>%
    filter(!is.na(Q2)) %>%
    mutate(question = "question") %>%
    ggplot(aes(x = question, fill = Q2)) + 
    geom_bar(position = "fill", width = .5) + coord_flip()+
    labs(y = "Percent", x = "") +
    theme_bw()
```

And here is some sample data:

```
 structure(list(Gender = c("Man", "Woman", "Woman", "Decline to answer", "Man", 
    "Man", "Woman", "Man", "Woman", "Man"), Religion_Importance = c("Very important", 
    "Not too important", "Not too important", "Not important at all", 
    "Somewhat important", "Very important", "Not too important", 
    "Not important at all", "Somewhat important", "Very important"
    ), Q2 = structure(c(1L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 4L, 1L), levels = c("Always or almost always", 
    "Generally", "Not generally", 
    "Never or almost never", "NA"), class = "factor")), row.names = c(NA, 
    -10L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

Comment: Please share a few rows of sample data so we have something to test your code on. Preferably use `dput()` so the sample data is in valid syntax and is copy/pasteable.

Comment: Oh sure, just added some in!

Answer (score 0):

I'd do something like this:

```
libary(tidyr)
library(dplyr)

df %>%
  pivot_longer(-Q2, names_to = "demog", values_to = "value") %>%
  mutate(group = paste(demog, value, sep = ":\n")) %>%
  ggplot(aes(y = group, fill = Q2)) +
  geom_bar(position = "stack", color = "gray60", size = 0.1) + 
  scale_fill_brewer(direction = -1) +
  scale_x_continuous(expand = expansion(mult = c(0, 0.05))) +
  labs(x = "Number of respondents", y = "", fill = "Q2 Response") +
  facet_grid(rows = vars(demog), scales = "free_y", space = "free_y")
```

[image]

You can have the bars all be the same length (and be filled proportionally) by changing `position = "stack"` to `position = "fill"`, but I think it's nice to have the total length of the bar show the number of respondents.